# No pods started after "kubeadm alpha certs renew"

Tags: kubernetes

I did a

```
kubeadm alpha certs renew
```

but after that, no pods get started. When starting from a Deployment, `kubectl get pod` doesn't even list the pod, when explicitly starting a pod, it is stuck on `Pending`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally I would follow a pattern to debug such issues starting with:

1. Check all the certificate files are rotated by `kubeadm` using `sudo cat /etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver.crt | openssl x509 -text`.
2. Make sure all the control plane services (`api-server`, `controller`, `scheduler` etc) have been restarted to use the new certificates.
3. If [1] and [2] are okay you should be able to do `kubectl get pods`
4. Now you should check the certificates for kubelet and make sure you are not hitting https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1753
5. Make sure `kubelet` is restarted to use the new certificate.

I think of control plane (not being able to do `kubectl`) and `kubelet` (node status not ready, should see certificates attempts in `api-server` logs from the node) certificates expiry separately so I can quickly tell which might be broken.

Comment: OK, after restarting ALL hosts including the control plane, they come back to life. Thanks!

Comment: @rabejens what did you mean by restarting ALL hosts?